# protractor- button click is not responding

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a button on a page that looks like:

```
button type="submit" name="username" value="123wq"
       class="user-option__action">test1</button>
<span class="user-option__description">TM</span>
```

I tried following code:

```
element(by.buttonText("test1")).click();
browser.actions().mouseMove(btntest1).click();
element(by.css('button[value="1"]')).click();
element(by.buttonText('test1')).click();

element.all(by.id('test1')).get(0).click();
element( by.css( '.select option[value="test1"]' ) ).click();
element(by.css('.test1')).click();

//selenium.click(NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH)
element(by.xpath('//input[@value='123wq'][@title='test1’]')).click();
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: What is the error message? Which of these clicks is failing? What did you observe?

Comment: i am getting  Message:
                                                                                                              Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://newpage1.com .If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular.
                              Please see 
                              https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load

Comment: Is this an Angular application?

Answer (score 0):

I understood poorly before, you want to use cssContainingText() http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText

so, it should look something like:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('button[type=submit]',"test1"))
```